# d3-js mouse wheel problems when activating and deactivating zoom behavior

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, zooming, mousewheel

I activate and deactivate the zoom behavior as seen in http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043 :

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", rescale)
// after adding the handler, the mouse wheel will still scroll the page

// activate
svg_g_element.call(zoom)
// now, the mouse wheel zoom

// desactivate
svg_g_element.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom")    

// now, the mouse wheel will neither zoom nor scroll while over the svg_g_element
```

How can a establish the default mouse wheel behavior to scroll the page? Or is the way show in the examples not the best way to deactivate the zoom behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will disable mousewheel zoom on Firefox as well.

```
svg_g_element
      .on("mousewheel.zoom", null)
      .on("DOMMouseScroll.zoom", null) // disables older versions of Firefox
      .on("wheel.zoom", null) // disables newer versions of Firefox
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to disable the zoom mousewheel event specifically with this.

```
svg_g_element.on("mousewheel.zoom", null);
```

Comment: I'm using 3.3.2 and this needed a slight correction. You have to use on("wheel.zoom", null)